# Popper align top dropdown

Tags: javascript, popper.js

Using popper.js

I'm unable to find how to align both the popper and the reference to the top by default, instead, it aligns the popper to the absolute middle of the reference.

I've tried the offset modifier which I can't seem to get right, it's either too far or doesn't even look like it's doing anything

```
modifiers: {
    offset: {
        enabled: true,
        offset: '100% - 25px,10'
    }
}
```

To use a picture to explain what I'm trying to achieve, imagine that I need to move the dropdown down until the blue line becomes straight:

[image]

Comment: `left-start` should give you the correct placement.